# In Julia, why use a Pair over a two element Tuple?

Tags: types, tuples, julia

When should I use a Pair over a two element Tuple and vice versa?

Comment: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/pair-a-b-vs-tuple-a-b/942

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mainly when you want to visually highlight, that there exists a relation between the first and second elements. For example, consider the following `Dict` construction

```
Dict(:a => 1, :b => 2)
```

Despite you can use `Tuple`, but it is more obvious here, that there is a relation between keys (`:a` and `:b`) and values (1, 2).

Actually, it is more than just obvious, it gives you the possibility to use the following definition

```
julia> Dict(((:a, 1) => (:b, 2)))
Dict{Tuple{Symbol, Int64}, Tuple{Symbol, Int64}} with 1 entry:
  (:a, 1) => (:b, 2)
```

Compare it with

```
julia> Dict(((:a, 1), (:b, 2)))
Dict{Symbol, Int64} with 2 entries:
  :a => 1
  :b => 2
```

By using only tuples it's hard to build a dictionary that can have tuples as keys.

Another, slightly different example can be found in `join` functions from [DataFrames.jl](https://dataframes.juliadata.org/dev/man/joins/)

```
innerjoin(a, b, on = [:City => :Location, :Job => :Work])
```

Here it is easy to understand, that you bind `City` column of `a` with `Location` column of `b`. Though, tuple syntax would be fine, but `Pair` notation looks more readable.

On the other hand, if you are building two-dimensional point there is no need in using `Pair`, usual Tuple is more than enough. `Point(x => y)` definition looks strange, compared to `Point(x, y)`.

So, the rule of thumb, if there is a relation between the first and second element use `Pair`, if they are independent of each other use `Tuple`.